# Filtering table based on customerID and closest transaction date to unique dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I am accessing a SQL Server table (*TransHistory*) that contains **CustomerID** and **TransactionDate** as my two fields of interest. Separately I have a list of **CustomerIDs** and **Dates of Interest** in an excel spreadsheet. I am trying to query the list of customers from excel spreadsheet in *TransHistory* where it outputs the closest past **TransactionDate** to the Date of Interest for that **CustomerID**.

*TransHistory* has hundreds of thousands of customers+transactions for which I'm querying for about a thousand customers and only need 1 unique row per customer. The **Dates of Interest** are unique to each customer (example entries from spreadsheet below) and won't always match the **TransactionDate** in *TransHistory* table, which is why I am querying for the closest past date to the **Date of Interest**.

| CustomerID | Date of Interest |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | 1/21/2022 |
| 22222 | 2/28/2013 |
| 33333 | 5/13/2018 |

The thing is I know how to do it in a multistep process of first querying all data in *TransHistory* for my **CustomerIDs** and then doing a subsequent query to then filter for the **Date of Interest**. When trying to simply/combine it into 1 query I get stumped by the fact that **Date of Interest** is unique to each **CustomerID**.

Would it be possible to filter for **CustomerID** while also filtering for **CustomerID** specific **Dates of Interest** in the same query? I am thinking it will require a two-dimensional array as a where statement, but I've never worked with them and not sure how to begin setting this up.
Would appreciate being pointed in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would provide the server with "Date of Interest" data and let the SQL Sever do the job

```
select top(1) with ties t.*
from Dates_of_Interest d
join TransHistory t on t.CustomerID = d.CustomerID
order by row_number() over(partition by d.CustomerID order by abs(datediff(d, t.TransactionDate, d.Date_of_Interest)))
```